# I can't make bootstrap dropdown to work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing problem in the dropdown in bootstrap. I have attached all the necessary file correctly. But still its not working.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#mainNavbar" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working

Comment: Explain what you expect the behaviour to be and what the exact problem is you are experiencing - please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: on clicking the button which is created the dropdown collapse is not working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your order of placing `jquery` and `bootstrap` is correct. Check below snippet which works correctly.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#mainNavbar" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mainNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```